Degree of sum or product of linearly independent algebraic numbers.
Let $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{A}$ such that $\alpha,\beta$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $deg(\alpha)=k_{1}, deg(\beta)=k_{2}$.
Can I deduce that $deg(\alpha \beta)=lcm(deg(\alpha),deg(\beta))=lcm(k_{1},k_{2})$, and $deg(\alpha +\beta)=deg(\alpha)*deg(\beta) $?
Can we prove these by closure properties of Algebraic numbers over addition and multiplication?(Since in proof of these, we need to construct minimal polynomials)
Note: For multiplication, I put least common multiple because:
$\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}$ has degree two not four.
Edit: 11:01PM
Note: For addition case, my idea is false by counterexample from user: KaleBhodre
Take $\alpha= \sqrt{2}$, and $\beta=1-\sqrt{2}$.
First: They are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ because:
Let $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that:
$a \alpha +b \beta=0$, Then $a=b=0$ is the only solution, so they are linearly independent.
Second: Degree of their addition is one not four.
Again but now by user user8268:
$\alpha=1+\sqrt{3}, \beta=\sqrt{2}$.
They are linearly independent but the degree of their multiplication is four not two.
How can I make conditions that avoid such counterexamples?

for the product it doesn't work either, e.g. $\alpha=\sqrt2$ and $\beta=1+\sqrt3$

Note: I've decided to keep this question because it provides valuable counterexamples that challenge common misconceptions students like myself may have.

Please don't use "EDIT:".  Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755
